# Discord Js - Bot not sending embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

**hi please i need some help the bot is giving an error which is  yourid , productownerid , productname is not defined in last steps i tried many codes but no one worked for me if anyone can help me please and thank you**

````java
  if(interaction.customId == 'evv'){
    let yourid = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('ask_1')
    let productownerid = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('ask_2')
    let productname = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('ask_3')
    let evalmsg = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('ask_4')
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
.setFields(
{ name: '**Buyer-Name**', value: `<@${yourid}>`}
{ name: '**Owner Of The Product**', value:`**<@${productownerid}>**`}
{ name: '**Product**', value:`**${productname}**`}
{ name: '**Message**', value: `**${evalmsg}**`}
)
.setFooter(`Requested By ${interaction.user.tag} , ${new Date()}`)
let button25 = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
  new MessageButton()
      .setCustomId('1')
      .setLabel("تقييم")
      .setStyle('PRIMARY')
      .setEmoji("")
)
await interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("1048414164932108289").send({embeds: [exampleEmbed],components:[button25]}) 
  }
the error is from here :

if (interaction.customId == '1'){
  const exampleEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("RANDOM")
.setFields(
{ name: '**Buyer-Name**', value: `<@${yourid}>`}
{ name: '**Owner Of The Product**', value:`**<@${productownerid}>**`}
{ name: '**Product**', value:`**${productname}**`}
{ name: '**Message**', value: `**${evalmsg}**`}
{ name: '**Evaluation**', value: `****`}
)
.setFooter(`Requested By ${interaction.user.tag} , ${new Date()}`)
interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("1048414164932108289").send({embeds: [exampleEmbed2],components:[]}) 
}
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<@${yourid}>`, you can use userMention(yourid) but i don't think it's the problem.
I think the probleme is the .setFooter for the date you don't have to do `${new Date()}` there is a command for this : .setTimestamp().
Or another problem you can't put "RANDOM" in .setColor

And I use new EmbedBuilder() instead of messageEmbed()

You also have to put "," at the end of a field like this :

```
.setFields(
  { name: '**Buyer-Name**', value: `<@${yourid}>`},
  { name: '**Owner Of The Product**', value:`**<@${productownerid}>**`},
  { name: '**Product**', value:`**${productname}**`},
  { name: '**Message**', value: `**${evalmsg}**`},
  { name: '**Evaluation**', value: `****`},
)
```

You also have to set a Title with .setTitle('title')

The last error i saw is for search a channel I use interaction.guild.channels.fetch('id')

So i propose you this correction :

```js
if (interaction.customId == '1'){
  const exampleEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('title')
  .setColor(15548997)
  .addFields(
    { name: '**Buyer-Name**', value: userMention(yourid)},
    { name: '**Owner Of The Product**', value: '**' + userMention(productownerid) + '**'},
    { name: '**Product**', value:`**${productname}**`},
    { name: '**Message**', value: `**${evalmsg}**`},
    { name: '**Evaluation**', value: `****`},
  )
  .setFooter(`Requested By ${interaction.user.tag}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  interaction.guild.channels.fetch("1048414164932108289").send({embeds: [exampleEmbed2]}) 
}
```